# Can you achieve multi touch with Android keyevents via ADB for scrolling screenshot

Tags: android, adb

I would like to try and initiate a scrolling screenshot on Android via adb keyevents. On the physical device this requires a three finger long press followed by the three fingers being  swiped to the bottom of the screen. I can achieve this for one finger by the following commands:

Long press

```
adb shell input swipe 100 500 100 500 500
```

Swipe

```
adb shell input swipe 100 500 100 1500 200
```

Is there a way to achieve the same for three touches?

I have tried using && to run multiple commands but his appears to be sequential so doesnt work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.